# Weird NSLookup Output

Tags: dns, nslookup

I'm attempting a lookup of authoritative DNS servers for class, and I'm currently turning up blanks even after requesting soa. Couldn't find any other posts on this, but a few kids in my class were having the same issue.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Here's the output.

```
dyn:~ AJFeather$ nslookup -type=soa yahoo.com
Server:     128.59.1.3
Address:    128.59.1.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
yahoo.com
    origin = ns1.yahoo.com
    mail addr = hostmaster.yahoo-inc.com
    serial = 2016040115
    refresh = 3600
    retry = 300
    expire = 1814400
    minimum = 600

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You are getting a DNS SOA RR back, and nslookup is displaying the data in it, which is what you asked for; in what way is the nslookup output "weird"? Please [edit] your question to tell us what you want to know, and we might be able to tell you.

Comment: There's no authoritative answers

Comment: well, in this case the authoritative answers come from the root servers, and resolve fine on my deb box. I'm thinking the DNS server you are using doesn;t have a valid root db or root.server file. http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/root-servers.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem – you asked for SOA records, and you *did* get SOA records. "Authoritative DNS servers" are not included in that – they're stored in the NS record type.

While some DNS resolvers also add the NS records to the 'Authority' section with normal replies, I can't find anywhere that would *require* them to be added in this situation. (They probably would be completely useless for most clients, since the reply has an actual answer anyway, so it's not like a stub client would suddenly stop using its configured servers and go full recursive out of the blue...)